# Title Column missing in Item Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, title, title-column

I am facing a very strange issue. When we created a subsite for one of our sites we were not able to add or edit any pages. We were getting an error:

> "You cannot edit this page".

On investigating further we noticed that the Site Pages library is missing the default Title column and instead we see a new column called "Client Application Page ID".

On checking the content type more we see that the Item Content type is missing the Title Column.

Any one know what could be the issue. This is only happening on the subsite.